# How can I populate a pandas dataframe column with tests on the value of another column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, contains, calculated-columns

Before I ask my question, I should say I think there's an easy solution to this that I'm missing entirely. I've searched google for an answer and get close but not quite to what I need.

I'm trying to find a way to check the values in one column of a dataframe and populate another new column with one of 4 values based on that first column.

I've tried to do several things to get what at what I'm doing. Since my "outcome_notes" column does not have standardized results, I'm hoping to standardize the results into 4 categories:

Complete
Pending
Incomplete
Canceled

I can try to do:

```
df1['outcome'].map({'complete': 'Complete', 'incomplete': 'Incomplete', 'Pending': 'Pending'})
```

but there are about 200 unique values in my complete dataset.

I've also tried to do use this but am not sure exactly how to get it to populate a column:

```
df1[df1['outcome_notes'].str.contains(r'\bcomplete', na=False)]
```

I tried creating new dataframes with this selection then merging them all, but it ends up providing thousands of extra rows.

I've struggled with an if then statement, but I fear my python skills make it so I don't actually know how to properly design the logic for this.

```
import pandas as pd
d  = {'id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'], 'outcome_notes': ['complete', 'pending', 'incomplete', 'canceled', 'completed', 'complete', '', 'completed -- doctor says', 'canceled due to doctor', '']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I'd really like a dataframe that looks like this:

```
d  = {'id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'], 'outcome_notes': ['complete', 'pending', 'incomplete', 'canceled', 'completed', 'complete', '', 'completed -- doctor says', 'canceled due to doctor', ''], 'outcome': 'Complete', 'Pending', 'Incomplete', 'Canceled', 'Complete', 'Complete', '', 'Complete', 'Canceled', '']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice this is base on you do not have misspellings in your `outcome_notes` . `str.findall`

```
s=df1.outcome_notes
df1['New']=s.str.findall('|'.join(s.iloc[:4])).str[0]
df1
Out[449]: 
   id             outcome_notes         New
0   1                  complete    complete
1   2                   pending     pending
2   3                incomplete  incomplete
3   4                  canceled    canceled
4   5                 completed    complete
5   6                  complete    complete
6   7                                   NaN
7   8  completed -- doctor says    complete
8   9    canceled due to doctor    canceled
9  10                                   NaN
```

---

Fuzzy match

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
a=s.iloc[:4]
matchdf=pd.DataFrame(s.map(lambda x : process.extract(x, a, limit=1)).str[0].tolist(),index=df1.index)
df1['New2']=matchdf.loc[matchdf[1]>60,0]
df1
Out[482]: 
   id             outcome_notes         New        New2
0   1                  complete    complete    complete
1   2                   pending     pending     pending
2   3                incomplete  incomplete  incomplete
3   4                  canceled    canceled    canceled
4   5                 completed    complete    complete
5   6                  complete    complete    complete
6   7                                   NaN         NaN
7   8  completed -- doctor says    complete    complete
8   9    canceled due to doctor    canceled    canceled
9  10                                   NaN         NaN
```

Comment: I only provided a portion of my actual data, and there are unfortunately quite a few spelling inconsistencies. That being said, I don't think I can solve for ALL the weird outliers, so this should be a huge step in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: @EduardoX let me offer you another solution , based on  fuzzy match

Comment: When defining a:
```
a=s.iloc[:4]
is the goal to get the first 4 values from s? Can I just replace a with my 4 desired values?

Comment: @EduardoX yes you can , just do a = ['Val1','Val2'...]